# Checking if any modulus of number with a range is zero

Tags: ruby, algorithm

There is a function d(n) which is defined as the sum of proper divisors of n (numbers less than n which divide evenly into n). E.g., the proper divisors of 220 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55 and 110; therefore d(220) = 284. The proper divisors of 284 are 1, 2, 4, 71 and 142; so d(284) = 220.

I want to implement this d(n) function in Ruby. My first instinct would be to use a for-loop to loop over all values up to n and check the modulus. The code below works:

I can get it to work with a for-loop like this:

```
def d(n)
  proper_divisors = []
  for i in 1...n
    if (n % i == 0)
      proper_divisors.push(i)
    end
  end
  return proper_divisors.inject(:+)
end
```

But from a previous answer I learned that `it's very rare to use a for loop in Ruby`. That's why I tried this:

```
def d(n)
  (1..n).inject(0) { |total| total+ n if (n % (1..n) == 0) }
end
```

So from the values from `1 to n` I start with `total` equal to 0 and add `n` to the `total` if `n` can be equally divided by a number from 1 to n. The part `if (n % (1..n) == 0)` does not work since `Range can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`.

How can I accomplish that I take the modulus of one number against a range and return true if it is equal to zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(fixed version of toro2k's answer)

```
def d(n)
  (1..n/2).inject(0) { |total, m| (n % m).zero? ? total + m : total }
end

d(220) # => 284
```

Block to `inject` accepts **two** parameters: the accumulator and current element of the collection. This block should return new value of the accumulator. In your code you ignore the current element (which makes you try dividing `n` by a range)

Comment: You can probably optimize the loop to `(1..n/2)`, seeing how nothing past `n/2` can be a proper divisor of `n`? Heh @AlokAnand, same thoughts ^_^

Comment: You need `n/2 + 1` / oh wait I used `1...n/2` ;-), `n/2` is fine.

Comment: No, it's now inclusive to `n/2`, (`1..n/2`), instead of exclusive before `(1...n)` (3 dots).

Comment: even if n is odd n/2 would do the task as it is sum of divisors, believe Indians in mathematics, just kidding :)

Comment: Hmm I do not see why the `(n % m).zero?` part loops through all elements from `1..n/2` with current element `m`.

Comment: @user2609980: `inject` does the looping.

Comment: Keep track of the smallest divisor greater than 1 that you find. Call this k. Stop after you check n/k.

Answer (score 2):

I have done the following:--

```
def d(n)
  (1..(n/2)).each_with_object(total = 0){|ele| total += ele if n%ele == 0 }
  total
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not as efficient as Sergio Tulentsev's answer, but simpler:

```
def d n
  (1..n / 2).select{|m| (n % m).zero?}.inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Why is this less efficient?

Comment: Because it iterates twice.

Comment: Actually for `n` up to 10^9 both yours and Sergio Tulentsev's solutions perform almost the same.